# Converting To Data Frame in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

In a specific data set, I have a column, 'starCustomer', that takes on these values:

```
[0, X, 0, 0, X, 0, X,...]
```

That is, each observation will contain a 0 if the person is not a Star Customer, but an X if that person is. I thought it would be a better idea to represent each X as 1 instead, so, I wrote the following code:

```
Star = df['starCustomer']
New_Star = [1 if x == 'X', else 0 for x in Star]
```

However, it is to my knowledge that New_Star is not a data frame, as we want it to be. So, I try to execute this following code:

```
Star = pd.DataFrame(New_Star)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Can anybody inform me on what's incorrect about this?

Comment: In your example `Star` is not a DataFrame either.  It is a Series.

Answer (score 1):

A column in a dataframe is an object of the class pd.Series

You can first add a new column to the dataframe:

```
df['New_Star'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'X' else 0 , axis=1)
```

You can now get a dataframe consisting only on the column `New_Star` with:

```
new_star_df = df[['New_Star']]
```

Note the double brackets, with a single bracket you will return the pd.Series, not the pd.DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you can just do this:

```
New_Star = Star.map({0: 0, "X": 1})
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't take care of the Data Frame problem! Also, when I type in New_Star just to see the data itself, I get an error about isinstance().

Comment: Actually, with some rearranging of the syntax, this approach works like a charm. Thank you!